# State replication of memory variables in a game/application server

Tags: load-balancing, session-replication

How does a cluster of servers behind a load balancer achieve the replication
of variables that are initialized during a client/server session? For example
when a client (let's say a game client) starts a session first with a load balancer that forwards the request to an available server, how does that server REPLICATES that session AND their memory STATES to the OTHER servers in a cluster?

```
                          LB
                          |
         App              App            App
          |
  (memory variable)
          |------------ replicated?
```

Or are the memory variables for the established session NOT replicated, and only session files are replicated in a database tier.. that wouldn't account for all the variables that a server must keep in memory.

It seems to me like to achieve synchronization in a multiplayer game, a cluster of servers must replicate all their states to other servers, but does that mean replicating all their memory variables?